# Regex difference: (\w+)? and (\w*)

Tags: regex, difference

Is there any difference between `(\w+)?` and `(\w*)` in regex?

It seems the same, doesn't it?

Comment: It does seem the same, except if you care about `""` vs. `null`

Comment: `(\w+)?` seems odd. Where did you see that? Any link to external resource please?

Comment: I saw `(\w+)?` in my company project

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`(\w+)?` and `(\w*)` both match the same (0..+inf word characters)

However, there is a slight difference:

In the first case, if this part of the regex matches `""`, the capturing group is absent. In the second case, it is empty. In some languages, the former manifests as a `null` while the latter should always be `""`.

In Javascript, for example,

```
/(\w*)/.exec("")  // ["", ""]
/(\w+)?/.exec("") // ["", undefined]
```

In PHP (`preg_match`), in the former case, the corresponding key is simply absent in the matches array: http://3v4l.org/DB6p3#v430

Comment: In which language the capturing of `""` results in **null** or empty string ?

Comment: @Cozzamara In the first case, an empty match is _not_ captured.

Comment: By which engine ? Both Perl and SED **do** capture empty string by both patterns

Comment: Thanks, I never realized that non-matched groups result in `undefined` instead of empty strings (since I always only check for truthiness)